# MapHubs doesn't map hubs and returns Error in X Application

Tags: asp.net, signalr, signalr-hub

I'm trying to implement simplest example ( https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/QuickStart-Hubs ) with WebSite ( I've been trying WebForms but sadly with same result )

in `Monitor.cs`

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs;

[HubName("chat")]
public class Chat : Hub {
    public void Send(string message) {
        // Call the addMessage method on all clients            
        Clients.All.addMessage(message);
        }
    }
```

in `Global.asax`

```
<%@ Application Language="C#" %>

<%@ Import Namespace="System" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.Routing" %>

<script runat="server">

    void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        // Code that runs on application startup
        RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs();
    }
```

in `Default.aspx`

```
<%@ Page Title="Monitor" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeFile="Monitor.aspx.cs" Inherits="Monitor" %>

<asp:Content ID="MonitorHeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>

    <script src="Scripts/jquery.signalR-1.0.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/signalr/hubs" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            // Proxy created on the fly          
            var chat = $.connection.chat;
            // Declare a function on the chat hub so the server can invoke it          
            chat.client.addMessage = function (message) {
                $('#messages').append('<li>' + message + '</li>');
            };
            // Start the connection
            $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
                $("#broadcast").click(function () {
                    // Call the chat method on the server
                    chat.server.send($('#msg').val());
                });
            });
        });
    </script>

</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">

    <input type="text" id="msg" />
    <input type="button" id="broadcast" value="broadcast" />
    <ul id="messages">
</asp:Content>
```

It doesn't work and when I click to `/signalr/hubs` I'm getting

```
    <span><h1>Server Error in 'XXX' Application.<hr width=100% size=1 color=silver></h1>
    <h2> <i>HTTP Error 404 - Not Found.</i> </h2></span>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If /signalr/hubs is responding with a 404, there is an issue with your call to `RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs();`. Either it is not getting called, or there is another route that was added to the `RouteTable` first which matches /signalr/hubs but then responds with a 404.

The "Why does signalr/hubs return 404 or Why do I get 'myhub' is undefined" of the [SignalR Faq](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/Faq) goes over this. If you still have trouble, you need to [debug](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx) your routes.

Comment: Biggest THANK YOU, The solution was right on the first link and it's : `<script type="text/javascript" src='<%= ResolveClientUrl("~/signalr/hubs") %>'></script>`

Answer (score 1):

With WebSite, in Default.aspx, use:

```
<script src="signalr/hubs" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I also updated the example in https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/QuickStart-Hubs.